# Pascal's triangle in Prolog

Tags: prolog, pascals-triangle

I have written a function for returning the next row in Pascal's triangle given the current row:

```
pascal_next_row([X],[X]).
pascal_next_row([H,H2|T],[A|B]):-
    pascal_next_row([H2|T],B),
    A is H + H2.
```

I want to be able to find the nth row in the triangle, e.g. `pascal(5,Row)`, `Row=[1,5,1,0,1,0,5,1]`. I have this:

```
pascal(N,Row):-
 pascalA(N,[1,0],Row).

pascalA(N,R,_Row):-
 N > 0,
 M is N-1,
    next_row([0|R],NR),
    pascalA(M,NR,NR).
```

Obviously `Row` should be the last one found before `n==0`. How can I return it? I tried using the `is` keyword, i.e. `Row is NR` but that isn't allowed, apparantly. Any help?

---

Trying to use `is` on lists gets me:

```
! Domain error in argument 2 of is/2
! expected expression, but found [1,4,6,4,1,0]
! goal:  _23592586 is[1,4,6,4,1,0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the base case, `N > 0` cancels your calculation...

```
pascalA(N,R,_Row):-
 N > 0, %% this evaluates to false so the calculation gets canceled
 M is N-1,
    next_row([0|R],NR),
    pascalA(M,NR,NR).

pascalA(0,R,R). %% this should be the base case... hope I got it correct...

pascalA(N,R,_Row):-
 M is N-1,
    next_row([0|R],NR),
    pascalA(M,NR,_Row).
```

Comment: I can't seem to use the `is` function on lists. I'm using SICStus, and I get the error 
`! Domain error in argument 2 of is/2
! expected expression, but found [1,4,6,4,1,0]
! goal:  _23592586 is[1,4,6,4,1,0]`

Comment: oh sorry... I forgot it was a list... I was writing this thing from memory (read: didn't test)... I think substituting `is` with `=` might work...

Answer (score 0):

You need a base case for pascalA where N = 0.